# python modulo why is 1-4 %5 not the same as (1-4)%5

Tags: python, modulo, parentheses

Does anyone know why the code below does not have the same outcome in Python?
Why do I need the parenthesis to get the correct outcome?

```
#example 1
print 1-4 %5
outcome: -3

#example 2
print (1-4)%5
outcome: 2
```

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Just like `1 - 4 * 5` and `(1 - 4) * 5`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! I guess I'm not that great at math :-)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).  Mod (`%`) takes precedence over `-`, so:

```
1-4 % 5 == 1 - (4 % 5) == 1 - 4 == -3
```

but

```
(1-4) % 5 == -3 % 5 == 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Python operator precedence has minus just lower than modulus

http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~valerie/courses/fall10/155/resources/op_precedence.html

```
*, /, % Multiplication, division, remainder
+, -    Addition, subtraction
```